# What is meant by this indicator function?

Tags: notation

In Hastie et al. (2009) p.509, it is written that $N_k=\sum_{i=1}^N I(C(i) = k)$. To my understanding, $I$ should be an indicator function.

However $C(i)$ is defined as "Each observation is assigned to one
and only one cluster. These assignments can be characterized by a many to-one mapping, or encoder $k = C(i)$, that assigns the $i$th observation to
the $k$th cluster".

How is the first expression an indicator function then? I don't see any true/false condition within the $I$.

Comment: How is $C(i) = k$ not a true/false condition?

Comment: @雨が好きな人 This is a clustering explanation. If the total number of clusters is $K$, $k\in\{1,\dots,K\}$ is an element of the set. $k$ can take any value in $1,\dots,K$ so I dont understand how it ever false

Comment: @雨が好きな人 in addition, $C(i)$ is an encoder which assigns an observation to cluster $k$. The way I see it $C(i)$ takes an observation $i$ and assigns it to cluster $k$, I don't understand how that can be false

Comment: In the sum, $k$ is one specific value from $\{1, \ldots, K\}$. Some $i$ will be assigned to cluster $k+1$ or to cluster $k-4$ for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$N_k=\sum_{i=1}^N I(C(i) = k)$ is counting the number of observations assigned to the $k$th cluster. It is the number of times $C(i) = k$ is true (meaning that observation $i$ is in cluster $k$) for a particular cluster $k$, iterating over all of the observations $i = 1, \dots, N$.